# SIP address for group chat in Lync

Tags: chat, sip, lync-2013

For opening the chat window with Microsoft Lync, we can call either

> Lync SIP:user@company.com

or

> SIP:user@company.com

However I am looking for single command for open a group chat. It can be by calling Lync with any command line parameter.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer just now and posting here for everyone. We can call Lync like below

```
Lync im:<sip:user1@host><sip:user2@host><sip:user3@host>
```

This will open a group chat window for all the three users. Source [Lync 2013 Command-Line Parameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg398376.aspx). One thing to remember is, do not give your own id in the SIP list as it will not open any chat window.

Comment: Does not work with office 365 unfortunately